# Tomcat embedded servlet throwing NoSuchMethodException for javax.servlet.ServletContext setInitParameter(String, String) despite method existing

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

I'm launching embedded tc7, (have tried 7.0.26 and 7.0.59) to run integration tests.  I've specified in the main project pom (which contains, among others, the integration module) that I want to use javax.servlet at least 2.5 (also tried 3.1.0) and I've stepped into the debugger to try and follow what happens, but it always fails with `NoSuchMethodException` inside `ServletContext.mergeParameters()` when calling

```
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : mergedParams.entrySet()) {
        sc.setInitParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());    // <---this one
    }
```

I've set all kinds of breakpoints and they don't indicate that there's a problem.  I've even used stopped the program at that line and used reflection in the NetBeans expression evaluator to no avail - reflection works!

```
java.lang.reflect.Method[] ms = sc.getClass().getMethods();
java.lang.reflect.Method sip = null;
for (java.lang.reflect.Method m : ms) {
  if ("setInitParameter".equalsIgnoreCase(m.getName()) {
    sip = m;
  }
}

sip.invoke(sc, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

That returns **true**, the first time and **false** subsequent times, as is expected for the method when using the same key.

I've checked the classpath and only see these up-to-date versions of libraries. There is a proprietary dependency that I have to include that relies on servlet-api, but I've added an exclusion to that in the dependencyManagement section of the pom so that it, too, should only be using 2.5 (or 3.1.0 - neither works).  I've checked the dependency tree of the root as well as the integration module and don't see any stale or old cruft in there.

I'm looking for any debugging tips to help find the culprate or other ways to include/exclude the RIGHT version of this.  It doesn't seem to cause a problem when running the actual server (which doesn't use embedded tomcat) but I'd like my tests to work, or even just understand wtf is going on.

I'll answer all questions as I'm sure this isn't quite clear. Sadly I can't provide running code to demonstrate, either at all or maybe just right now.  I'll try to reproduce the scenario without proprietary jar's.

tl;dr(ish) - `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext` has a private method `mergeParameters()` that calls `getServletContext().setInitParameter(String, String)`. The `ServletContext` returned is an `ApplicationContextFacade` which appears to have that method, and the method can be called with reflection, but when directly called throws `NoSuchMethodException`... Please help me find other ways to debug or ferret out the *REAL* class (that doesn't have the method).

Comment: I guess you should clarify your problem first not try to debug.

Comment: Well, I'm at a loss... I am looking for advice or an explanation of:
1) is NetBeans lying to me about the class and classpath?
2) why would reflection work to call a method that can't be called directly (and it's not a proxy)
3) could a class be included via a dependency even after it's put in the exclusions section and does not show up in `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`?

It's a complete mystery to me at this point, so I tried to provide enough background to get direction.

Comment: You are saying "the method can be called with reflection" because you can see it in the debugger or because you put some code there that would execute it through reflection and this code works?

Comment: I used the debugger to execute code that calls the method with reflection. This is standard Apache code that's already compiled, so I didn't pull that down and modify the Tomcat source directly.